# Load testing example on CloudBees

Tags: load-testing, cloudbees

I have a question about the load test example on this page: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Monitoring .

In the load test results chart, could you please explain what's happened during the "Load test temporarily halted" ? Why the response times is increased while the number of requests serviced decreased?

Thanks in advance
Leon

Comment: I guess they temporarily *removed* the added servers which leads to a sharply decreasing number of requests processed and a spike in the response time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an artefact (noise) of the graphing calculations. As the number of requests dropped dramatically - the window of calculations for request time still was closing over a time window that spanned into when there were a lot of requests. So there was data that said "a lot of time is being spend in request" but then more current data said there were few requests - so the result was a temporary spike (you can see a dip where it partially corrects).

Also, it looks like a single data point - hence the straight line being interpolated up. Given there are few requests, it is also possible that there were some that did actually take a lot of time (perhaps there was a GC pause) - and that is more visible than it would otherwise be.

Over a longer period of time, and if you "zoom out" then it would probably appear to just be a glitch/quirk (for the purposes of this, I think you can ignore it).